# Unable to import Enums from Prisma.Schema with Deno

Tags: typescript, postgresql, prisma, deno

prisma.schema

```
enum Level {
  Info
  Warn
  Error
}

enum LogType {
  Request
  Internal
}
```

My index.ts where I'm trying to import those enums to use as function parameter types.

```
error: Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './generated/client/deno/edge.ts' does not provide an export named 'Level'
import { Level, LogType } from "./generated/client/deno/edge.ts";
```

Am I importing from the correct place or am I trying to use these incorrectly?